# How to find a method where used in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there a way to find one method where used in intellij idea with golang plugin ?

I need to find the method all where used.

Anyone who know how to do this?

Answer (score 5):

**Find Usages** is for sure the right way how it was already mentioned. However, if you don't want going through the context menu, you could also use the shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> for Windows/Linux or <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> for Mac OS. You can also specify the Find Usages *Scope* which can be, for example, only production files or only test classes. Other shortcuts could be found from [here](https://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/intellij-idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf).

Unfortunately if you use Ubuntu this shortcut is already reserved for some system operation and to make it working in Intellij IDEA you need to disable it in OS level.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the method name and select "Find Usages". This will find direct callers of the concrete method. If you want to find callers who call the method via an interface, it's harder. If you know the interface(s), you can navigate to each of them in turn and right click on the method name and select "Find Usages". If you don't know which interfaces include the method, [Go Oracle](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/oracle) can help.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the Find Usages on a method finds every method of that same name, so if you use a common method name, it will find a lot more than you want.  For example, I am debugging legacy code that had a method called clone(), not an override, just a new method.  When I did a Find Usages on it, it found over 1000 entries, most of which were in the JDK, which clearly did not call the method of interest.
My solution was to slightly rename the clone() method to cloneXYZ() and rebuild. The compiler showed me the 5 calls I was looking for.